# Accessing Scrapy via a webservice

Tags: python, json, web-services, scrapy

I've had a search around SO and the web in general, and haven't been able to find a solution to my issue; so I thought I would raise a question here.

I'm currently playing around with Scrapy, and am successfully retrieving the data I need from my target website.

The creation of the spider is part of a larger project, and so I need to work out a way of getting the results from the spider into my website.

I don't want to access the database with the spider, because there is a variety of logic that would need to be applied to the data before it was stored, and I wouldn't want to have to repeat that logic elsewhere.

What I'm thinking is perhaps a webservice, that receives a JSON object as a request; and returns a JSON object with the result.

I'm fairly new to Scrapy and Python in a websetting, but I have read the Scrapy docs. Whilst there is a webservice for Scrapy, that seems to be more to do with the monitoring of spiders; and not returning results.

Any help and thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure why you are looking for Scrapy implementation of webservice, can't you just use the results to do this manually, using the `json` and `urllib2` modules from python?

Comment: I want to leverage the work that Scrapy does, with the ease of use of calling it with a web service. 

My website is written in PHP.

Comment: There is already `scrapyd` it is a web application to schedule crawler. You can call it(using `curl`) to save the result in a file then you can access the result with your application.

Comment: Do you think that would be better than accessing it through a web service?

Comment: I think that it is a good idea to use `scrapyd`( its is designed for such job, launch and log spiders ) but I am not sure. You can ask in the [scrapy google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scrapy-users) and then post the answer here.